# ApplicationDbContext ToListAsync() not returning 'Id' Column data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Asp.NET MVC noob here

I have an `AppUserRepository` with a task:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AppUser>> GetAllForFirm(Tenant tenant)
        {
            return await _context.AppUsers.Where(u => u.Tenant == tenant && u.isDeleted == false).ToListAsync();
        }
```

I am then calling this task like so:

ViewModel:

```
public List<AppUser> UsersForFirm { get; set; }
```

Controller(`AppUserController`):

```
string username = User.Identity.Name;
AppUser user = await _appUserRepository.GetByUsernameAsync(username);
AppuserViewModel avm = new AppuserViewModel();
avm.UsersForFirm = (List<AppUser>)await _appUserRepository.GetAllForFirm(user.Tenant);
```

*(For extra context, each `AppUser` has a 'Tenant' object associated)*

This almost works fine, and `avm.UsersForFirm` now holds an `AppUser` list where a given `Tenant` object is associated and I can extract all relevant info like UserNames, Email Addesses, lastLoggedIn dates etc. All good so far...

However, when I try to assign the `avm.Id`, it appears as though my `GetAllForFirm` task is returning a blank `Guid` `(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)` for each `AppUser` returned. If I check my database (in the `AspNetUsers` table, where all my `AppUser` info is stored), all `AppUsers` have a valid ('not' blank) `Id` and this is the only infomation that differs from the results of the `GetAllForFirm()` task.

Is anyone able to explain why this is, and what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How **Guid** is saved in database and can you specify the column type?

Comment: @AT-2017 My `AppUser` model stores the Id like so: `[Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }` and stores in the AspNetUsers table as `PK, nvarchar(50), not null`. This has surprised me a little, as I expected it to be `uniqueidentifier` - could this be a conversion issue from `String` to `Guid`?

Comment: What's stored in database, did you check? It should be something like this to store - `Guid val = Guid.NewGuid()`;

Comment: @AT-2017 I'm assuming in my case you mean from my initial migration? If so, `Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was because I had an Id field in my `AppUser.cs` Model.

Removing these lines

```
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Key] //<----------- This one
        public string Id { get; set; }//<----------- And this one
```

Is what fixed it for me. After this, many other problems I was having were fixed too, such as User.IsInRole always returning false (and indeed anything else to do with user roles).

I spent 3 whole days trying to work this out, I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and by pass the viewmModel

This is the controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using WorkshopPro.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

   public class UsersAdmin : Controller
        {
            private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
            private readonly YourContext _cs;
    
    
            public UsersAdmin(UserManager<ApplicationUser> usrMgr, YourContext cs)
            {
                userManager = usrMgr;
                this.roleManager = roleManager;
                _cs = cs;
            }
    
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Tenant == tenant && u.isDeleted == false).ToList());
            }
    }
```

Then under your View

```
@model IEnumerable<YourProject.Areas.Identity.Data.AppUser>

<table>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried bypassing the ViewModel completely and it's not worked. I also tried querying the database directly - `string testID = _context.Users.Single(x => x.UserName == "myUserName").Id.ToString();` and that also returned `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`, even though the Id for that user in the database is `2C674530-CE78-4914-8A57-5E695F4C36EC` and 'all' the other information like email address can be returned no problem. I'm pretty sure it's a datatype conversion issue somewhere (the datatype in DB is `nvarchar(450)`, but is `Guid` in my project), I just work out how to solve it